# Convert an array to tab-delimited Mailchimp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, mailchimp

I need to convert a JSON array to a tab-delimited version so that I can save it as a .txt file so it can be uploaded on Mailchimp.

I would need result like this:

"Date","Pupil","Grade"

"25 May","Bloggs, Fred","C"

"25 May","Doe, Jane","B"

"15 July","Bloggs, Fred","A"

Comment: how's your initial JSON?

Comment: @mrReiha

[
        { "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "gender": "female" },
        { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "gender": "male" },
        { "firstName": "Akexander", "lastName": "Beth", "gender": "male" },
        { "firstName": "Sarah", "lastName": "Kelly", "gender": "female" }
        { "firstName": "Rachel", "lastName": "Haiworth", "gender": "female" }
    ]

Comment: where's tab then? do you need tab between your values? and where should date come from?

Comment: values above are just structure example. This is what I've found on their page https://mailchimp.com/help/tab-delimited-file-tips/?_ga=2.224092955.1863871633.1544630546-1391322392.1544528932 I'm confused a bit as well. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if whether this helps or not, but you can follow this structure and make any other small details to match your desired output ( I have no idea where should `date` and `grade` come from, but this is just an example ):

```
var json = '...your json string here...',
    objects = JSON.parse( json ),
    output = [],
    finalString = '';

for ( let item in objects )
    output.push([
        new Date,
        objects[ item ].lastName + ', ' + objects[ item ].firstName,
        objects[ item ].gender
    ]);
```

*Update*:

You need to save each array inside of that `output` along a new line for your final string to save as `.txt`:

```
output.forEach( v => finalString += v.join( "\t" ) + "\n" )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's very helpful.